# Couchbase N1QL - inline Regex captured group replace?

Tags: sql, regex, go, couchbase, sql++

```cs
UPDATE SOME_BUCKET as doc USE KEYS ["USER_ACCESS::123456::SOME_ROLE", "MORE KEYS HERE...", etc]
loc.id = REGEXP_REPLACE(loc.id, "(.*) - (.*)", "$1-$2") FOR loc IN locations END
RETURNING doc
```

Setting the "loc.id" here just assigns it the string literal replacement value, **"$1-$2"** *instead of the back references to the captured groups*.

Couchbase Server runs GoLang regex syntax, which apparently might not support back references? What alternative is there?

Comment: try https://regex101.com/r/XbzYcu/1

Comment: @Edward -- thank you, although I've got that in the REGEXP_REPLACE method, **2nd + 3rd params**. Question is how to properly loop through a nested array while calling that REGEXP_REPLACE method...

Comment: i see now,  sorry

Answer (score 0):

Update required SET, UNSET clause https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/update.html#update-for
Check Example 3

```
UPDATE SOME_BUCKET as doc 
USE KEYS ["USER_ACCESS::123456::SOME_ROLE", "MORE KEYS HERE...", etc]
SET loc.id = REGEXP_REPLACE(loc.id, "(.*) - (.*)", "$1-$2") FOR loc IN locations END
RETURNING doc;
```

Comment: I had the SET command originally, but it kept setting the value to "$1-$2", the string literal replacement. I'm wondering if this is a **back reference** limitation in GoLang Regex (per Couchbase docs, _"Couchbase Server N1QL supports regular expressions supported by The Go Programming Language..."_